# Wrap a group of divs of various classes with another div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a series of classes like this:

```
<div class="groupLabelHeader">Countertop Dimensions</div>
<div class="option1">Option</div>
<div class="option2">Option</div>
<div class="option3">Option</div>
<div class="groupDivider"></div>
```

I want to wrap all of the options pertaining to countertop dimensions inside of their own div, regardless of the html inside.

So it will look like this:

```
<div class="countertopDimensions">
    <div class="groupLabelHeader">Countertop Dimensions</div>
    <div class="option1">Option</div>
    <div class="option2">Option</div>
    <div class="option3">Option</div>
</div>
<div class="groupDivider"></div>
```

I tried the .wrapAll() but it wraps the div around each element rather than all of them.

Comment: Use `.wrapAll()`, not `.wrap()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `.countertopDimensions` `div`, insert it before `.groupDivider` and then move elements inside `.countertopDimensions`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $wrapper = $('<div class="countertopDimensions"></div>');
  $('.groupDivider').before($wrapper);
  $('.groupLabelHeader,.option1,.option2,.option3').appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

```css
.groupLabelHeader,.option1, .option2, .option3 {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.countertopDimensions .groupLabelHeader, .countertopDimensions .option1, .countertopDimensions .option2, .countertopDimensions .option3 {
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="groupLabelHeader">Countertop Dimensions</div>
<div class="option1">Option</div>
<div class="option2">Option</div>
<div class="option3">Option</div>
<div class="groupDivider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$("button").click(function(){
        $("div:not('.groupDivider')").wrapAll("<div class='hello'></div>");
    });
```

Comment: I agree with this one. OP may not need the click listener, but the rest of it is golden (save the wrong class name for the wrapper, but I'll let it go). https://jsfiddle.net/21zw7dLL/